# The function plt.show() not working in Spyder

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I am making a simple regression model on Spyder. Whenever I call `plt.show()` the image of the graph does not popup.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(x_train, y_train, color ='blue')
plt.plot(x_train, train_pred, color ='purple')
plt.title('Salary VS Experience',color = 'maroon')
plt.xlabel('Experience',color='brown')
plt.ylabel('Salary',color ='red')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you show us the data you're using?  It could be an issue with the data as well.  When you say "graph does not pop up", are you saying that the actual figure doesn't show, or the data doesn't show and the graph is empty?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Is the figure shown inside the console or no figure is generated at all? Please be more specific.

Comment: The figure is only generated at the console/ kernel.. But it should appear in a separate window... With more specific data right?

Comment: I am using a course at udemy, and my code was the same as the instructor's but... His graph window pops up.... But mine only at, console.. With not so clear data

Comment: Show us an actual snapshot.

Comment: You can adjust the spyder settings under Tools/Preferences/IPython console/graphics

Comment: ok,i will try this and tell you the rsults

Comment: What to actually adjust in the settings?